# Sort Columns in advancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, advanceddatagrid

I'm making an application where I display an AdvanvedDataGrid with one column with dates(in format DD/MM/YYYY) and another with datetimes (in format HH:MM). I'd like to sort dates according with the datetimes as well(just clicking in the header of the column), there is an examplen of the expected behaviour:

**02/02/2011 | 10:42**

**03/02/2011 | 09:45**

**02/02/2011 | 11:45**

**03/02/2011 | 11:30**

So clicking in the "date" header sort the dates taking into account the datetimes:

**02/02/2011 | 10:42**

**02/02/2011 | 11:45**

**03/02/2011 | 09:45**

**03/02/2011 | 11:30**

I'm trying using the AdvancedDataGridColumnGroups with it does not work, any suggetions or ideas to start working?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
This is the code for my adg:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG" width="100%" height="100%" color="0x323232"
    dataProvider="{_currentDatosBusqueda}" verticalScrollPolicy="auto"
    fontSize="10" fontFamily="Arial" fontStyle="normal" fontWeight="bold" doubleClickEnabled="true"
    itemDoubleClick="dobleClickFilaDataGridBusqueda(event);" useRollOver="true">        


<mx:columns>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Paciente ID" dataField="patientID"  paddingRight="0" resizable="false"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Apellidos y nombre de paciente" dataField="patientName" resizable="false"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Fecha del estudio" dataField="studyDate"  paddingRight="0" textAlign="right" resizable="false"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Hora del estudio" dataField="studyTime"  paddingRight="0" textAlign="right" resizable="false"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Accesion Number" dataField="accesionNumber" paddingRight="0" resizable="false"/>

</mx:columns>
```

_currentDatosBusqueda is an arraycollection I receive from the Server (with the correct format of dates and datetime).

Answer (score 3):

Supply full date into date column, but render only date part with `labelFunction`. For label function, create `formatDate` like that:

```
import mx.formatters.DateFormatter;

private var formatter:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
//somewhere in init function
formatter.formatString = "DD/MM/YYYY";

private function formatDate(item:Date, column:DataGridColumn):String {
    return formatter.format(item);
}
```

Sorting on this column should take into account full date.

**Edit**: OK, data is formatted on server. But nothing prevents you from combining it into full date/time object and use it on two columns with corresponding labelFunctions. Simple and robust.

Comment: Thx for your reply but I format correctly the dates and hours before displaying in the adg, my problem is how to sort multiple columns attending a one criteria. I do not know if I have to make a function by myself or if flex has support for that matter.

Comment: I just think it's much easier to restore full date in one column than implement sorting on multiple criteria. Never heard about such thing in Flex, it's open source though, but this isn't going to be simple.

Comment: ...and you can do same trick with hours column, using hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: I do not know if it is a strange behaviour but it's something I need to do, so how can you sort columns in an adg? Where is the event to listen?

Comment: Columns are sorted automatically comparing data objects in clicked column (you can supply custom sortCompareFunction for column). To sort them manually, sort the data provider.

Comment: Could you tell me how to implement that sortCompareFunction?? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can sort the columns of my advandedDataGrid setting the compare function to the HeaderRelease property but I still having an error cause the **little arrow dont show the sort direction**, how can I set it?

My headerRelease function is:

```
public function onHeaderRelease(evt:AdvancedDataGridEvent):void
        {
            evt.preventDefault();

            var srt:Sort = new Sort();
            var fields:Array = new Array();

            if( evt.columnIndex == lastIndex )
            {
                desc = !desc;
            }
            else
            {
                desc = false;
                lastIndex = evt.columnIndex;
            }

            fields.push( new SortField( evt.dataField, true, desc ) );
            if( evt.dataField != "studyDate" && evt.dataField !="studyTime" )
                fields.push( new SortField("studyDate", true, true) );
            if( evt.dataField != "studyTime" )
                fields.push( new SortField("studyTime", true, false) );

            srt.fields = fields;

            var ar:ArrayCollection = myADG.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
            ar.sort = srt;
            ar.refresh();
        }
```